# How can I move data from BigQuery or DataPrep to Firestore?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataprep

I just cleaned up my firestore collection data using DataPrep and verified the data via BigQuery. I now want to move the data back to Firestore. Is there a way to do this?

I have used manual method of exporting to JSON and then uploading using a code provided by AngularFirebase. But It is not automated as there is a need to periodically cleanup this data.

I am looking for a process within Google Cloud console. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, more like a partial answer. I could not add a comment as I don't have 50 reputation yet. I am in a similar boat but not entirely the same situation. My situation being that I want to use a subset of BigQuery data and add it to Firestore. My thinking is to do the following:

1. Use the [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries) API to query the data periodically using [BigQuery Jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load)' Load (in your case) or Query (in my case)
2. Convert it to JSON in code
3. Use [batch commit](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions) in Firestore's API to update the firestore database

This is my idea and I am not sure whether this will work, but I will you know more once I am done with this. Unless someone else has better insights to help me and the person asking this question